# Adding GridTiles to List<Widget> dynamically

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have a list of players and I want to render this list to GridTile Buttons. How can I do this? I already tried doing a function that returns GridTiles as a list, but could not get it to work. I've already read something about maps.

My approach is, to have buttons which contain the name and the number of the player. (Player is a class i've created)

This is my example atm:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
    players.add(new Player("Tom", 10, "test"));
    players.add(new Player("Mike", 22, "test"));
    players.add(new Player("John", 33, "test"));

    List<Widget> list = new List<Widget>();
    list.add(new Text("Test"));
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Players'),
      ),
      body: new GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        children: new List<Widget>.generate(16, (index) {
          return new GridTile(
            child: new Card(
                color: Colors.blue.shade200,
                child: new Center(
                  child: new Text('tile $index'),
                )
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi tom, can you please clarify what are you actually trying to achieve? and what is the issue you are facing.

Comment: I wanna render the list players as buttons. Foreach player in players there has to be a button. But I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class Players{
  int id;
  String name;
  Players({this.id,this.name});
  //Getters
  String get getName => name;
  int get getID => id;
}

class DemoPageGridTile extends StatelessWidget {

   List<Players> _listData = new List<Players>();

 DemoPageGridTile(){
   _generateList();
 }

  _generateList(){
    for(int i=0; i<45; i++){
      _listData.add(Players(id: i+1, name: "xyz_$i"));
    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("GridTile example"),
      ),
      body: GridView.builder(
       gridDelegate:  new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 4),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
           return Container(
             margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
             child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: (){ print(_listData[index].id.toString()); },
              child: Text(_listData[index].getName),
            ),
           );
      },
        itemCount: _listData.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]